# Rendering a 3d wpf model as an image and passing back to a website

Tags: wpf, 3d

I have a requirement to do the following.

1. Pass a set of variables from a website to a backend webservice
2. Apply the variables to a WPF 3D model.
3. Generate an image and pass back to the website.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you'd need to trigger the WPF program remotely, possibly using remoting, and then you'd have to write the resulting image out to a file or stream which could then be rendered back over the pipeline as a byte array. It wouldn't be pretty code, but it is workable.

Answer (score 0):

[RenderTargetBitmap](http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/3_Bitmap.html) do the job.